# Dúvida no logoff em php

Tags: php, html

Alguém teria alguma ideia do motivo pelo qual mesmo ao destruir a sessão que armazena o login de um usuário logado no site, ao se acessar a `url` diretamente é mostrado como se o usuário se mantivesse logado, mesmo após a chamada da da `session_destroy()`;?

> **index**

```
<li class="nav-item">                       
<a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Sair" data-placement="bottom" href="pag-login.php" target="_self">

<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>

<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>

// CHAMADA DO ARQUIVO QUE DESTROY AS SESSION:
<a href="sair.php"></a>

</li>
```

> **sair.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

unset(
    $_SESSION['email'],

    $_SESSION['id'],
    $_SESSION['tipo_user'],
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado']);
session_destroy();

header('Location: pag-login.php');
exit();
```

Comment: o que você quer dizer com "é mostrado como se o usuário se mantivesse logado"  ? Ainda está aparecendo as informações que você guardou?

Comment: Exatamente isto aí!

Comment: Bianca tenta fazer assim `$_SESSION = array();` no lugar do `unset`

Comment: Qual é o teste que você faz para ver se o usuário está logado ou não em cada página?